# Cannot change column/row heights of a table in a div

Tags: html, css

I am generating a table using my `Vertical_Table function`. When I remove the table from the `div` I can adjust the dimensions of the rows and columns but when it is inside the `div` I cannot change them. Any ideas why? Here is some jfiddle so you can see what I am talking about http://jsfiddle.net/6XAHR/

**CSS CODE**

```
> #Pallate
{
border: 1px solid black;
position:relative;
top:40px;
margin:0 auto;
width:1200px;
height:360px;
background-color: #C8C8C8;
}

#Scroll_Table_Border
{
Position:relative;
top:40px;
Left:320px;
border: 1px solid black;
height:275px;
max-width: 850px;
background-color: #C8C8C8;
}

#Scroll_Table {
left:25px;
top:25px;
white-space: nowrap;
Position:Absolute;
height:225px;
max-width: 800px;
width: 100% !important;
overflow:auto;
background-color: #C8C8C8;
}

#Button_Group_Title
{
Position:Absolute;
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5px;
background-color:  #C8C8C8;
top:30px;
Left:35px;
z-index:2;
}
#Scroll_Table_Title
{
Position:Absolute;
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5px;
background-color:  #C8C8C8;
z-index:2;
top:30px;
Left:335px;
}


#Button_Group {
text-align:center;
padding-top:30px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-right:25px;
padding-left:25px;
border: 1px solid black;
position:Absolute;
top:40px;
left:20px;
height:230px;
width:200px;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: #C8C8C8;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div ID = "Pallate" >
<div ID = "Scroll_Table_Title">Trial Information</div>
<div ID = "Button_Group_Title">View Results</div>

<div ID = "Button_Group">
     <input type="button" ID = "Paper_Information" onclick="changeContent(this.id)" value="Paper Information" class = "Class_Button">
     <input type="button" ID = "Trial_Information" onclick="changeContent(this.id)" value="Trial Setting" class = "Class_Button">
     <input type="button" ID = "Results" onclick="changeContent(this.id)" value="Trial Results" class = "Class_Button">
     <input type="button" ID = "Control_Law" onclick="changeContent(this.id)" value="Control Algorithm" class = "Class_Button">
     <input type="button" ID = "Exercise" onclick="changeContent(this.id)" value="Exercise" class = "Class_Button">
     <input type="button" ID = "Actuator" onclick="changeContent(this.id)" value="Pump Properties" class = "Class_Button">
     <input type="button" ID = "Sensor" onclick="changeContent(this.id)" value="Glucose Sensor" class = "Class_Button">
     <input type="button" ID = "Blood_Glucose_Safety" onclick="changeContent(this.id)" value="Blood Glucose Safety" class = "Class_Button">
     <input type="button" ID = "Reference_Glucose" onclick="changeContent(this.id)" value="Reference Measurements" class = "Class_Button">
</div>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
 <div ID = "Scroll_Table_Border">
         <div ID = "Scroll_Table">
          <?php 
          $Columns  = 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE Table_NAME = \'Control_Law\'';
          $Columns = sqlsrv_query($dbhandle,$Columns);
          $Sets = array(sqlsrv_query($dbhandle, 'SELECT * FROM Control_Law WHERE [Paper ID] = ' . $ID));

          $i = 0;
          while ($Row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($Columns))
          {
            $Column_Vector[$i] = $Row[0]; $i++;
          }
          $Table_ID = 'Advanced_Table';
          $Columns_Vector = array($Column_Vector);
          Vertical_Table($Columns_Vector,$Sets,'40px','',$Table_ID);
          ?>
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you replace your PHP with a generated HTML sample, and put the whole thing in a jsfiddle.net please.

Comment: Are you applying the styles to the td element?  CSS is really picky about that and you HAVE to apply any table elements to the lowest node in the table (the <td>)

Comment: I just posted the jfiddle which has the style of my table,divs and everything else.

Comment: @Joe Packer, yes I apply my styles to the <td> element. Please have a look at my jfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/6XAHR/

Comment: Shouldn't your HTML "id" be lowercase? not sure if it matters...

Comment: Seems to work either way..

Comment: @Gaven Which <td> are you trying to make smaller or longer?

Comment: If you look at my jfiddle, the problem is that the row has a fixed height but is way too long. I want the row height to grow and the width to shrink. if I remove the max-width constraint in my #Scroll_Table ID, it resizes the columns and rows perfectly but then the overflow property stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #Scroll_Table {
      left:25px;
      top:25px;
      white-space: nowrap; //REMOVE THIS
      Position:Absolute;
      height:225px;
      max-width: 800px;
      width: 100% !important;
      overflow:auto;
      background-color: #C8C8C8;
 }
```

This will get it to drop down then you can set the max width.  The problem with the text you have in there now is it is all 1 string with no spaces.  Remove the spaces and it will drop down normally.  Hope this helps!